# No system in Service Maintenance while generating OData service

Tags: odata, sap-basis, sap-gateway

I generated my Service over Transaction "SEGW" and everything is fine, but after I generated the services (MPC and DPC) no "Service maintenance" occurs like in all tutorials i've done.

[image: my own service without "service maintenance" folder]

Is there a way to generate an entry in the maintenance folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see any entry in the *Service Maintenance* folder because you are missing some *system alias* settings that are used by the service generator. Anyhow, you can also register your service via transaction ***/IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE***.

For more details about the missing settings, take a look at the following [topic](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3711226) on SCN.

Cheers,
SePo

Answer (score 0):

If the deployment system is absent in Service Maintenance you can add it manually that way.

**In SPRO**:

*SAP NetWeaver -> Gateway Service Enablement -> Backend OData Channel -> Connection Settings to SAP NetWeaver Gateway -> SAP NetWeaver Gateway Settings*

Create the new entry and put RFC connection of local system from SM59 there.